# Генератор словаря в python3

Tags: python

С помощью генератора словаря и строки

```
languages = ‘Python Golang PHP C# Java'
```

создайте следующий словарь:

```
{‘Python‘: ‘P’, ‘Golang’: ‘G’, ‘PHP’: ‘P’, ‘C#’: ‘C’, ‘Java’: ‘J’}

languages = 'Python', 'Golang', 'PHP', 'C#', 'Java'
dic = {i: x for i, x in enumerate(languages, 1)}
print(dic)
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Создайте. В чём сложность то? ))

Comment: languages = 'Python', 'Golang', 'PHP', 'C#', 'Java'
dic = {i: x for i, x in enumerate(languages, 1)}
print(dic)
Не создаётся как нужно

Comment: Ну так посмотрите, что у вас получается. Подумайте - что не так, что нужно задать в качестве ключа и значения, чтобы было так. И зачем вам `enumerate`, где у вас в задании просьба о нумерации, числах в качестве ключей словаря?

Comment: Учиться, учиться и еще раз учиться!

Answer (score 0):

Как-то так:

```
{ s: s[0] for s in langs.split() }
```

Comment: Ну зачем на такое то простое учебное задание ответ давать )  Тем более если попыток решения вообще нет.